# How to push Array values to input box?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi who can push the values here into the input box instead o the alert box?? Please keep the uniqueness and output the whole list.

```
Names:<input id='names'/>

var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var uniqueNames = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i].website) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(data[i].website);        
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
   alert(uniqueNames[i]);    
}
```

Please help as no one online has done it!!

Comment: What have you tried? No doubt someone might type the code for you for the reputation, but you won't learn anything. Please show us your attempt(s), we'll help you fix it from there. It is rather simple if you know the basics of JavaScript.

Comment: **push the values here into the input box** what does it mean

Comment: @user2181397 I assume they want the text to be appended to a textbox or input.

Comment: @Script47 I commend this brave stab into the dark.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "no one online" has done whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Damon And if that's true, that may indicate that there's some fundamental problem with what OP is trying to do...

Comment: @Script47 I have tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/C97DJ/291/. As you can see it is simple to display the values to the alert and iterate through but how do we show the values in the textbox?

Comment: @user2181397 yes I want the text appended to the textbox.

Comment: Well I have looked online and all examples of unique iterations show output to alert boxes or span, none output to text boxes or autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part answer as it's not appending to textbox but I managed to append it to a list: Although my HTML here and JS and JSON is in a partial (MVC5) and don't know if this is good practice in the long run or not. But I am happy I have half an answer and as developers we will always learn more and more as it's all developmental! And hope this will help someone ;-) Answer:

```
HTML: 
Names:<p id="uniqueWebsites"></p>

JS:
var uniqueNamesRes = "";

var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var uniqueNames = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i].website) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(data[i].website);        
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
  uniqueNamesRes += uniqueNames[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("uniqueWebsites").innerHTML = uniqueNamesRes;
```